# Python asyncio server keeps running even after program termination

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

In our code, we create an app which captures webhooks using aiohttp web.Application() with the server by means of loop.create_server() method.

Sometimes (read - difficult to reproduce but often enough) the listening server keeps running even after the code termination.

Eg.:

```
> sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
systemd-r  463 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4   2459      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
sshd       689            root    3u  IPv4  22779      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd       689            root    4u  IPv6  22781      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
python3   2728          ubuntu    7u  IPv4 334240      0t0  TCP *:8991 (LISTEN)
...
python3   2808          ubuntu    7u  IPv4 351159      0t0  TCP *:8991 (LISTEN)
```

This leads to the case when the ghost server (or servers in some bad cases) eats request intended for the living causing mayhem :)

We run pure asyncio - no threads - no multiprocessing. Anyone has any idea how this happens and how to prevent this from happening? **Is there some sort of context manager or approach that I can use, that will kill the webserver after the program finishes?**

Edit:

- This happens when the program reaches the end of the code and exits normally (shutdown is being called)

Example of the bare code...

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web

WEBHOOK = "/listen"

class WebServer():

    def __init__(self):
        self.app = web.Application()
        self.app.router.add_post(WEBHOOK, self.webhook_streams)
        self.server = None

    async def start(self, local_ip, local_port):
        if self.server:
            return
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.server = await loop.create_server(
            self.app.make_handler(),
            local_ip,
            local_port,
            reuse_port=True, # This will allow to bind to already used port, otherwise it will simply fail if there is ghost server present
        )

    async def webhook_streams(self, raw):
        pass

async def shutdown(self):
    print("Shutting down..")
    asyncio.get_event_loop().stop()
    pending = asyncio.Task.all_tasks()
    for task in pending:
        task.cancel()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    ws = WebServer()
    await ws.start("0.0.0.0", 8000)
    # ....some other stuff....
    await shutdown()
```

Comment: How and when does the program get terminated or killed? What happens if it has a session with a client when that happens?

Comment: I have made the edit to make it more clear... does it answer your questions in detail?

Comment: Probably still add more debugging details. Can you add a few `print` or perhaps `logging.warning` statements to see whether it gets stuck in the `for task in pending:` loop or even before that?

Comment: That's a good point! Thanks, I will try this and I will get back when I get the results...

Answer (score 1):

The key was to actually wait till the server properly closes all connections... eg. this needed to be added to the WebServer class

```
   async def stop(self):
        "stops server"
        if not self.server:
            return True
        self.server.close() # this must be synchronous which is confusing
        await self.server.wait_closed() # here you actually wait for server to close
        "stopped server...."
        return not self.server.is_serving()
```